# How to change the image position according to the orientation in ios?

Tags: ios, image, constraints, xcode-storyboard, ios-autolayout

In portrait I am having two images in the corners one is on the left top and the another on the bottom right.When I rotate the two images stays in the same corner.But I need the whole portrait screen to be rotate left by 90 degree. Here is the images

1) Image 1

[image]

2) Image 2

[image]

Though i have tried using constraints and auto layout to fix the images but failed.

Need help thanks in advance.

Comment: ...need more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your question:
You should look at [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html). You can design different layouts and button arrangements in storyboard using the different size classes. You can watch 2min 30sec of the Stanford iOS8 course about Size Classes [here](https://youtu.be/oNl7qpUvQ1k?t=1m15s), that can give you a quick intro on the topic.

Comment: size classes are used to change height and width for images, i need to change position of image when its orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Do it through Size Classes!!! 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

check it For Refrence !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its also a key reference for me.